# Why doesn't model-query return query results? (clj-plaza)

Tags: clojure, triplestore

I am using [`clj-plaza`](http://antoniogarrote.github.com/clj-plaza/documentation/2010/05/05/rdf.html) (0.0.5-SNAPSHOT) to query a Sesame/Jena Model. The function `model-query` does not appear to execute the query. It returns the internal representation of a `clj-plaza` query instead.

```
(init-jena-framework)
(def *m* (build-model))

(with-model *m*
 (model-add-triples
  (model-to-triples 
    (document-to-model "http://www.rdfdata.org/dat/rdfdata.rdf" 
                       :rdf))))

(def all-subjects-query 
 (defquery
  (query-set-vars [:?subject])
  (query-set-pattern (make-pattern [[:?subject ?p ?o]]))
  (query-set-type :select))

;; As expected
(model-query-triples *m* all-subjects-query)
=> clojure.lang.LazySeq@2e1e8502

;; Does not execute query (?)
(model-query *m* all-subjects-query)
=> {:kind :select, :pattern [[:?object :?p :?o]], :vars [:?object]}
```

The official [tutorial](http://antoniogarrote.github.com/clj-plaza/documentation/2010/05/05/rdf.html) claims `model-query` returns a list of bindings from the query:

```
({:?object "http://randomurl.com/asdf"}
 {:?object "http://asdf.com/qwer"})
```

Comment: second this! i opened issue on [it's github](https://github.com/antoniogarrote/clj-plaza/issues), but no reply..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug.

Here is a [fix](https://github.com/frenchy64/clj-plaza/commit/402766dfa3aa5cecf279c175055f9015e4828009). Until it is merged back and updated on clojars, feel free to use my [fork](https://github.com/frenchy64/clj-plaza).

A workaround would be to use `(query model query)` (instead of `model-query`)after importing the corresponding Jena or Sesame implementation.

For Sesame:

```
(use 'plaza.rdf.implementations.sesame)
(init-sesame-framework)
(def *m* (build-model))

(with-model *m*
 (model-add-triples
  (model-to-triples 
    (document-to-model "http://www.rdfdata.org/dat/rdfdata.rdf" 
                       :rdf))))

(def all-subjects-query 
 (defquery
  (query-set-vars [:?subject])
  (query-set-pattern (make-pattern [[:?subject ?p ?o]]))
  (query-set-type :select))

(query *m* all-subjects-query)

=> [{:?s #<SesameResource http://www.rdfdata.org/dat/rdfdata.rdf>} 
{:?s #<SesameResource http://www.rdfdata.org/dat/rdfdata.rdf>} 
{:?s #<SesameResource http://www.rdfdata.org/dat/rdfdata.rdf>} 
{:?s #<SesameResource http://www.rdfdata.org/dat/rdfdata.rdf>} 
{:?s #<SesameResource http://rdfweb.org/topic/FOAFBulletinBoard>} 
{:?s #<SesameResource http://rdfweb.org/topic/FOAFBulletinBoard>} ...
```